# PostgreSQL Get top-k minimum per range

Tags: postgresql-9.3, greatest-n-per-group, top

Assume I have the following data:

```
| f1 | f2 | f3 |
|----|----|----|
|  1 |  1 |  1 |
|  1 |  1 |  5 |
|  1 |  2 |  3 |
|  1 |  2 |  6 |
|  1 |  3 |  4 |
|  1 |  3 |  7 |
|  2 |  1 |  2 |
|  2 |  1 | 22 |
|  2 |  2 |  3 |
|  2 |  2 |  4 |
```

There are two f3 values maximum per each f1,f2 combination.

For this specific example, I want to get top-2 minimum values per f1 and range (f2 - max(f2) per f1).

Example output:

```
| f1 | RNG| f3 |
|----|----|----|
|  1 |1 -3|  1 |
|  1 |1 -3|  3 |
|  1 |2 -3|  3 |
|  1 |2 -3|  4 |
|  1 |3 -3|  4 |
|  1 |3 -3|  7 |
|  2 |1- 2|  2 |
|  2 |1- 2|  3 |
|  2 |2- 2|  3 |
|  2 |2- 2|  4 |
```

To create the field RNG is not required. I only added it to show that for `f1=1`, there are 3 ranges: `1-3, 2-3, 3-3` created by the distinct values of `f2` for `f1=1`. For each such range I want to calculate the top-k minimum values per f1 and range.

SQL Fiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9ddbb/1

Building the Ranges may be done by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.f1,s1.f2 AS range_from ,s2.f2 AS range_to
FROM dbTable s1,
(SELECT f1,MAX(f2) AS f2 FROM dbTable
GROUP BY f1) s2
WHERE s1.f1=s2.f1
ORDER BY s1.f1,s1.f2;
```

Is there any way to achieve that, without building intermediate DB tables?

Comment: What should happen if there are ties?

Comment: @ypercube Ties should be no problem, since I only want the upper two even if the third one is the same as the 2nd. Row_number() should have no problem.

Comment: I mean, what if there are rows with `(1,1,3), (1,1,4), (1,2,3), ...`. Should the two `3` appear (`1 |1 -3|  3 and  1 |1 -3|  3`) or one 3 and one 4 (`1 |1 -3|  3 and  1 |1 -3|  4`)?

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for clarifying that crucial detail. They should appear as two 3 and not 3,4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way, using the `LATERAL` syntax, available from 9.3+ versions::

```
WITH t AS
  ( SELECT f1, f2,  
           MAX(f2) OVER (PARTITION BY f1) AS range_to
    FROM dbTable 
    GROUP BY f1, f2
  ) 
SELECT t.f1, 
       -- t.f2 AS range_from, t.range_to,
       t.f2 || ' - ' || t.range_to AS RNG,
       x.f3
FROM t
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT f3 
      FROM dbTable 
      WHERE f1 = t.f1 AND f2 >= t.f2 
      ORDER BY f3 LIMIT 2
    ) AS x (f3)
ORDER BY t.f1, t.f2, x.f3 ;
```

Test at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9ddbb/15).

Or without the CTE:

```
SELECT t.f1, 
       -- t.f2 AS range_from, 
       -- MAX(t.f2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.f1) AS range_to,
       t.f2 || ' - ' || MAX(t.f2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.f1) AS RNG,
       x.f3
FROM dbTable AS t
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT f3 
      FROM dbTable 
      WHERE f1 = t.f1 AND f2 >= t.f2 
      ORDER BY f3 LIMIT 2
    ) AS x (f3)
GROUP BY t.f1, t.f2, x.f3
ORDER BY t.f1, t.f2, x.f3 ;
```

Comment: Upvoted and accepted since it is more elegant and advanced than my brute-force approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think this query is correct:

```
SELECT f1,range_from,range_to,f3 FROM
(
/* s53 subquery joins original table and created ranges */
SELECT s.f1,s3.range_from,s3.range_to,s.f3, row_number() over (partition BY s.f1,s3.range_from ORDER BY f3) AS counter 
FROM dbTable s,
(
/* Created ranges are the s3 subquery */
SELECT DISTINCT s1.f1,s1.f2 AS range_from ,s2.f2 AS range_to
FROM dbTable s1,
(SELECT f1,MAX(f2) AS f2 FROM dbTable
GROUP BY f1) s2
WHERE s1.f1=s2.f1
ORDER BY s1.f1,s1.f2
) s3

WHERE s.f1=s3.f1 
AND (s.f2 >= s3.range_from AND s.f2<= s3.range_to)
ORDER BY s.f1,s3.range_from,s.f3
) s53
WHERE counter<=2
ORDER BY f1,range_from,range_to, counter;
```

And seems to give the correct output in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9ddbb/11/0) :

```
| f1 | range_from | range_to | f3 |
|----|------------|----------|----|
|  1 |          1 |        3 |  1 |
|  1 |          1 |        3 |  3 |
|  1 |          2 |        3 |  3 |
|  1 |          2 |        3 |  4 |
|  1 |          3 |        3 |  4 |
|  1 |          3 |        3 |  7 |
|  2 |          1 |        2 |  2 |
|  2 |          1 |        2 |  3 |
|  2 |          2 |        2 |  3 |
|  2 |          2 |        2 |  4 |
```